# PHP MySQL Displaying database data in a clean table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using this following code to display my members list on my website, this works as an example:

```
<?php
// Adam's Custom PHP MySQL Pagination Tutorial and Script
// You have to put your mysql connection data and alter the SQL queries(both queries)
// This script is in tutorial form and is accompanied by the following video:  
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8xYGnEOXYc
include 'core/init.php';
//////////////  QUERY THE MEMBER DATA INITIALLY LIKE YOU NORMALLY WOULD
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT userid, first_name, last_name FROM users ORDER BY userid ASC");
//////////////////////////////////// Adam's Pagination Logic    //
$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); // Get total of Num rows from the database query
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { // Get pn from URL vars if it is present
$pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(new)
//$pn = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(deprecated)
} else { // If the pn URL variable is not present force it to be value of page number 1
$pn = 1;
}
//This is where we set how many database items to show on each page
$itemsPerPage = 10;
// Get the value of the last page in the pagination result set
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);
// Be sure URL variable $pn(page number) is no lower than page 1 and no higher than $lastpage
if ($pn < 1) { // If it is less than 1
$pn = 1; // force if to be 1
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { // if it is greater than $lastpage
$pn = $lastPage; // force it to be $lastpage's value
}
// This creates the numbers to click in between the next and back buttons
// This section is explained well in the video that accompanies this script
$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . 

$add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}
// This line sets the "LIMIT" range... the 2 values we place to choose a range of rows from database in our query
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage;
// Now we are going to run the same query as above but this time add $limit onto the end of the SQL syntax
// $sql2 is what we will use to fuel our while loop statement below
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT userid, first_name, last_name FROM users ORDER BY userid ASC $limit");
//////////////////////////////// END Adam's Pagination Logic ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////// Adam's Pagination Display Setup /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$paginationDisplay = ""; // Initialize the pagination output variable
// This code runs only if the last page variable is ot equal to 1, if it is only 1 page we require no paginated links to display
if ($lastPage != "1"){
    // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';
    // If we are not on page 1 we can place the Back button
    if ($pn != 1) {
        $previous = $pn - 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
    }
    // Lay in the clickable numbers display here between the Back and Next links
    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
    // If we are not on the very last page we can place the Next button
    if ($pn != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $pn + 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////// END Adam's Pagination Display Setup ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Build the Output Section Here
$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

    $id = $row["userid"];
    $firstname = $row["first_name"];
    $country = $row["last_name"];

    $outputList .= '<h1>' . $firstname . '</h1><h2>' . $country . ' </h2><hr />';

} // close while loop
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adam's Pagination</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.pagNumActive {
    color: #000;
    border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;">
     <h2>Total Items: <?php echo $nr; ?></h2>
   </div>
      <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
      <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;"><?php print "$outputList"; ?></div>
      <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue with this is it displays the information really rough and horrible looking. I haven't inserted it into my website design yet. I was hoping to get the information rendered in a neat table used on my website, here is a standard code for that empty table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            #
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            First Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Last Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Username
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            1
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Mark
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Otto
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @mdo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            2
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Jacob
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Thornton
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @fat
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            3
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Larry
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            the Bird
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @twitter
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

How could I get the information from the top code to show in the neat table? Obviously the code would have to automatically add new rows and columns once a new user signs up or whatever so not really sure how to do this? And I'm pretty new to PHP and MYSQL so if you could provide details that would be amazing!

Thank you!

Comment: You make a loop that echos the data. `echo '<tr><td>' . $data[i] . '</td></tr>';`

Comment: Please don't post your entire code like that. Only post the relevant part. Noone wants to spit through 1000 lines of code just to find the one function we need. Also, as @developerwjk mentioned, this can be done by looping over your query result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the while with something like this:

```
$outputList = '<table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            #
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            First Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Last Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Username
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

    $id = $row["userid"];
    $firstname = $row["first_name"];
    $lastname = $row["last_name"];
    $username = $row["username"];

    $outputList .= '<tr>
                        <td>' .
                            $id . 
                        '</td>
                            <td>' .
                            $firstname .
                        '</td>
                            <td>' .
                            $lastname .
                        '</td>
                              <td>' .
                            $username .
                        '</td>
                    </tr>';
}

$outputList .= '</tbody>
            </table>';
```

Comment: You should add the `username` field to `$sql2` in order to be able to use it in `$outputList`